# Can't change max_locks_per_transaction in docker postgres container

Tags: postgresql, docker, linux-kernel, locks

i am using docker image `kartoza/postgis:9.6-2.4` to perform django tests. The main problem is that it complains `out of shared memory` and in logs it suggests to increase `max_locks_per_transaction`.
Firstly, I tested **locally** passing `EXTRA_CONFIG=max_locks_per_transaction=512` as an environment variable for the docker container and inside i saw the change by running:

```
test=# SHOW max_locks_per_transaction;
 max_locks_per_transaction 
---------------------------
 512
(1 row)
```

Then i tried to do the same on **another server** where CI jobs run on Jenkins but it didn't change. I tried manually starting a container there and coudldn't see that parameter changes, rather it stayed with default value of `64`.

Below some information of SHMMAX and other parameters that can affect the problem.

**/etc/sysctl.d/30-postgresql-shm.conf**

```
# Shared memory settings for PostgreSQL on Linux

# The settings here are upper limits; performance is not affected if the
# settings are larger than necessary. If other programs use shared memory as
# well, you will have to coordinate the size settings between them.

# Maximum size of a single shared memory segment in bytes
#kernel.shmmax = 33554432

# Maximum total size of all shared memory segments in pages (normally 4096 bytes)
#kernel.shmall = 2097152
```

**ipc -l**

```
------ Messages Limits --------
max queues system wide = 32000
max size of message (bytes) = 8192
default max size of queue (bytes) = 16384

------ Shared Memory Limits --------
max number of segments = 4096
max seg size (kbytes) = 18014398509465599
max total shared memory (kbytes) = 18014398442373116
min seg size (bytes) = 1

------ Semaphore Limits --------
max number of arrays = 128
max semaphores per array = 250
max semaphores system wide = 32000
max ops per semop call = 32
semaphore max value = 32767
```

Anyone has an idea?

Comment: Are you using parallel query? What is the query that triggers that error and its execution plan?

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe Yes there are parallel queries. It is basically testing process. I understand that causes the lock.

Comment: System V shared memory settings don't apply, as PostgreSQL uses POSIX shared memory. Your choice is to either disable parallel query (`max_parallel_workers_per_gather = 0`) or raise the limits in Docker (I have no idea how to do that).

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe Thanks for the suggestion. It is already set to 0. I realize now the problem is not with parallelism.

Comment: You get that error when running a query, right? Do you have very many tables?

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe I didn’t write the test cases. But inside it creates DB through django and perform tests using it. This process is repeated several times in parallel for different code. Each client has custom and shared libraries and testing is for each client in parallel the way I described.