# Handling Out of Shared Memory Error in PostgreSQL (container) with 80K Sub Partitioned Tables

Tags: postgresql, docker, shared-memory, postgresql-15

I have PostgreSql 15.3 running as a docker container.
My docker run configuration is
`-m 512g --memory-swap 512g --shm-size=16g`

Using this configuration, I loaded 36B rows, taking up about 30T between tables and indexes.
I loaded with about 24 parallel operations, and the pg driver was using connection pooling, so there were about 150 concurrent connections but not all active.
My postgresql.conf was set to

```
max_connections = 512 
max_locks_per_transaction = 1024
```

All of this ran without any problem.

The 36B row table is sub-partitioned. The layer with actual data has about 80,000 tables.
Parent, partitioned by category, each partitioned by year, each partitioned by month, each partitioned by sensor id, which is the 80K tables of data.

My problem is that for the life of me, I cannot perform a simple `COUNT(*)` on the top level table without the
`out of shared memory, you might need to increase max_locks_per_connection`. In fact, I can count from a single table and from the month partition, but not from the year partition, which is only about 10K tables.

Reading that I need the lock table to hold max_connection * max_locks in shared memory, I've tried lowering the max_connections, and increasing both max_locks and shared memory but without success.
Currently I am at
`-m 512g --memory-swap 512g --shm-size=64g` for the container and

```
max_connections = 8 
max_locks_per_transaction = 163840
```

in the config, having gone by increments of course.

I do have a second table partitioned the same way, much smaller volume of data, but also 80K tables with data.
From what I've read, something like

```
max_connections = 100 
max_locks_per_transaction = 1600
```

should cover 160K tables, and if each lock takes 168 bytes, the shared memory needs only at least 26M.

Any suggestions on what I should be modifying and how I should be calculating the target values?

Comment: Why so many partitions? Looks like you have an average of just 450.000 records per partitions, that's next to nothing. When aiming for a 500 million records per table, you would only need 70+ partitions. I would start removing the month-partitions, that would already reduce the number of partitions by a factor 12.

Comment: @FrankHeikens If ultimately there is a limit to the number of partitions Postgres can allow, then yes, I would work around it, but I've yet to see such a limit documented. The data is not evenly distributed and many sensors will have 2-4 milion rows. However, the main reason is that the data is continually updated at the sensor level, so DROP/ATTACH PARTITION at that level minimizes overall locking during updates, a strategy recommended in the docs at 5.11.2.2. Partition Maintenance

Comment: Have you verified the max_* config settings are actually in use?  How did you got about setting these on an already existing database in a docker container?

Comment: @jjanes One simply mounts a `postgresql.conf` file to the container and the configuration is read whenever the container is started. The settings can be edited just like an on-host instance.

Comment: I would first validate the entire strategy. For me, partitioning for a mere 450.000 records doesn't make sense, that's too small. Instead of months, you could stick with a year and the average partition will be a 5.4 million records. Still a small number of records, but you would end up with "just" 6700 tables instead of 80.000 Another issue would be autovacuum, vacuum on 80.000 tables is very different than just 6700 tables.

Comment: Does the error persist if you set `max_parallel_workers_per_gather` to 0?

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe Setting `max_parallel_workers_per_gather 0` changed the query plan from `Parallel Index Only Scan` per table to `Index Only Scan` per table, but issued the same oo-shm error when needing to lock more than a few hundred tables. Now that I've learned the 'locks needed' include indexes, it's clear my factor of indexes x tables is not going to work here, no matter how high I set max_locks_per_conn.

Comment: Makes sense. I only wanted to rule out that you are going out of shared memory with parallel query.

Comment: @jjanes You nailed it! Turns out the most critical configuration setting discussed here, `max_locks_per_transaction` for some strange, undocumented reason, is not overwritten if changed in the config file attached to the docker container, but only if passed into the `docker run` command as a `-c` option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Having a ridiculous number of partitions is going to require a ridiculous number of locks.  The number of `max_connections * max_locks_per_connection` you show should be able to handle 80000 tables in a simple case of unindexed tables with flat partitions, but indexes also need to be locked during planning even if they don't end up being used in the execution.  The deep partitioning structure will also require some more locks, but without a test script to reproduce your exact structure I haven't tested to see how many it would need.

Handling partitions gets more and more unwieldy the more partitions you have. That is going to put a practical limit on the number of partitions you can have long before you reach a hard limit.  I would say you are already over the practical limit.

These problems are just internal to PostgreSQL.  If you were hitting memory problems at the OS/VM level, I would expect those to fail with different error messages than the one you see.

The locking issues should be the same whether the tables are populated or just exist but empty, so if you need to test things it should be easy to do just be exporting the structure without the data (like `pg_dump -s`).

Comment: Okay, _"indexes also need to be locked even if not used in the execution"_. That explains why doing a COUNT(*) on one lowest level partition required 11 locks, and at the month level, with 700 tables, was taking out 20,000 locks, and why this is now unmanageable for Postgres at the top partition level. Yes, the partitions are moderately indexed, including the sub-partition table definitions, to match the shaping and analytics needs. Was never a problem and in fact necessary with the non-partitioned version.

Answer (score 0):

The final answer is indeed "**you have too many partitions**".

***HOWEVER***, the actual solution to my *specific* question lies in the behavior of the PostgreSql docker image and specifically *it seems to ignore* `max_locks_per_transaction` if modifed in a config file attached to the container. It needs to be passed into the `docker run` command line as a `-c` option instead.

Thanks @jjanes for suggesting verifying the values were read.

When you run a postgres container, you can attach your own config file:

```
$ # run postgres with custom config
$ docker run -d --name some-postgres 
             -v "$PWD/my-postgres.conf":/etc/postgresql/postgresql.conf 
             postgres -c 'config_file=/etc/postgresql/postgresql.conf'
```

Of course, you usually need to stop and restart the container to modify the configuration setting.
If you modify the config file with

`max_connections = 333` (some non-default number),

start the container, and issue

```
SELECT name, setting FROM pg_settings WHERE name = 'max_connections';
      name       | setting
-----------------+---------
 max_connections | 333
```

Now do the same with `max_locks_per_transaction` and for the `postgres:15.3` image no matter what you set it to you get

```
      name                 | setting
---------------------------+---------
 max_locks_per_transaction | 256
```

This is hinted at in [Cant change max_locks in docker](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65093609/458354) and at [Change max_locks for github actions](https://github.com/docker-library/postgres/discussions/1091#discussion-5253852)

The configuration *seems* to be respected only if passed in on the `docker run` command line

```
$ docker run -d --name some-postgres 
             -v "$PWD/my-postgres.conf":/etc/postgresql/postgresql.conf 
             postgres -c 'config_file=/etc/postgresql/postgresql.conf' 
                      -c max_locks_per_transaction=1024
```

Once I did this, and set `max_locks_per_transaction` to a ludicrous number (500,000), I was able to issue a count against the next higher partition level.

That said, the second solution to my question lies in the detail that most discussions around this very issue seem to not mention. `max_locks_per_transaction * max_connections` needs to cover not just the number of all partitioned tables, ***but also each and every index on them***. Thanks @jjanes again.

In my case, each table has about 10 indexes. A query against one table needed 11 locks. Against the month partition needed 21,000 locks, and against the year partition needed 218,000 locks. Clearly unsustainable.

The sobering fact is that PostgreSql partitioning does not scale horizontally as comfortably as many other features and may not lend itself well to matching the logical organization of your business domain.

### Update:

Happy outcome to the story.
I collapsed my sensor partitions up to the month level.
For category/year/month I ended up with 265 partitions (2/10/12).
With the same indexes in place, could query

```
     month   49 locks
      year  382 locks
full table 5128 locks
```

and executed with a 4x improvement in speed and parallelization over the non-partitioned table